# Android: dynamically change ActionBar icon?

Tags: android

I would like to dynamically change the "home" icon in the ActionBar.  This is easily done in v14 with ActionBar.setIcon(...), but I can't find anyway to accomplish this in previous versions.

Comment: Does anything happen when you call `setIcon`? And if you're trying to accomplish things in anything pre-Honeycomb, you should take a look at [ActionBarSherlock.](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: I am using a customized ActionBar-esque component for pre-v11 (similar to ActionBarSherlock).  This is for v11-v13 (honeycomb).  When I call setIcon in honeycomb, I get a methodnotfound exception.

Comment: setIcon is only available in API levels >= 14

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using the [ActionbarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) code provided by google, you can access the home icon via the ActionBarHelperBase.java class for API v4 onwards.

```
    //code snippet from ActionBarHelperBase.java
    ...
    private void setupActionBar() {
    final ViewGroup actionBarCompat = getActionBarCompat();
    if (actionBarCompat == null) {
        return;
    }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams springLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    springLayoutParams.weight = 1;

    // Add Home button
    SimpleMenu tempMenu = new SimpleMenu(mActivity);
    SimpleMenuItem homeItem = new SimpleMenuItem(tempMenu,
            android.R.id.home, 0, mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name));
    homeItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_ftn);
    addActionItemCompatFromMenuItem(homeItem);

    // Add title text
    TextView titleText = new TextView(mActivity, null,
            R.attr.actionbarCompatTitleStyle);
    titleText.setLayoutParams(springLayoutParams);
    titleText.setText(mActivity.getTitle());
    actionBarCompat.addView(titleText);
}
...
```

You should be able to modify the code to the home button accessible to the activities that extend ActionBarActivity and change it that way.

Honeycomb seems a little harder and it doesn't seem to give such easy access. At a guess, its id should also be android.R.id.home so you may be able to pull that from the view in ActionBarHelperHoneycomb.java

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  `Activity.findViewById(android.R.id.home)` works.

Answer (score 22):

If your actionbar works like Sherlock and is based on menu items, this is my solution:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem switchButton = menu.findItem(R.id.SwitchSearchOption);     
    if(searchScriptDisplayed){
        switchButton.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_precedent);
    }else{
        switchButton.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_search);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Comment: well, for honeycomb I use the actionbar provided by the sdk. so, I'm trying to find a honeycomb equivalent of the ActionBar.setIcon() method provided in v14.

Comment: Thanks for this great snippet - been looking for this for a while!

Comment: it works for all items. But I get a crash with nullpointer exception if I use it for the home icon (android.R.id.home).

Answer (score 1):

I would say you do something like this :

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_drawer);
```

see the link [How to change the icon actionBarCompat](http://fast-howto.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar will use the android:logo attribute of your manifest, if one is provided. That lets you use separate drawable resources for the icon (Launcher) and the logo (ActionBar, among other things).