#  change Action Bar icon

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar

Is it possible to change the **action bar** icon dynamically?

I have set it in my manifest. I want to change it and set it through the code.

**My manifest**:

```
    <activity android:name=".plugin.importer.face.FaceActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SYNC" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />              
        </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/new_enabled">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: dynamically change ActionBar icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090332/android-dynamically-change-actionbar-icon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // || getActionBar();
    actionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_enabled));
```

Hope that helps