# ActionBar Sherlock Progress Bar in Icon space

Tags: android, progress-bar, actionbarsherlock

I am using an Action bar in my project. I am displaying a progress bar via the below approach.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

However, what I'd really like to do is replace the left most image icon with the progress indicator when arbitrary background processes run and then returns the usual icon when complete.

Can anyone tell me the steps needed to replace this icon with a functional Progress indicator. It only needs to be an intermediate one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can find some suggestions here: [Android: dynamically change ActionBar icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090332/android-dynamically-change-actionbar-icon).

Specifically, you can access the icon by using

```
Activity.findViewById(android.R.id.home)
```

And then just set and re-set the icon as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom layout for this and use `actionbar.setCustomView(yourcustomlayout);`

In your custom layout have an imageView(which is your app icon) and progress bar(initially which is set to invisible).

When running the background process just set the visibility between image view and progress bar.

Comment: It sounds plausible advice. I'l give it a go.